# how do you parse log files in R quickly?

Tags: r

there is big files in a directory called c:/logs. I need to reach each log, grep for a few regular expressions and put the output to a data frame. This is what I have a and it is taking a very long time to run:

```
final<-data.frame()
path<-c("C:/logs")
logs<-dir(path, pattern = "log", full.names = TRUE, ignore.case = TRUE)

toMatch <- c("compile.cancelSwapCode", "compile.insertCode", "compile.getCode",
             "compile.getCodes","compile.getCodeWithAnalysis")

for (i in logs){
  print(i)
  xx <- readLines(i)
  xxx<-grep(paste(toMatch,collapse="|"),  xx, value=TRUE)
  df<-read.table(text=xxx)
  final<-rbind(final, df) 
}
```

The actual file sisez are 150MB. Is there a quick way to do this?

example log file:

```
2016-11-02 00:00:01,506 INFO  [[(JSK) mux request dispatch][/][tid=1234][compileController.Code]] - Received request for test request: [ticket=test101]
2016-11-02 00:00:01,514 INFO  [[(JSK) mux request dispatch][/][tid=1234][compileController.Code]] - request: [ticket=test101] found in cache, returning from Cache
2016-11-02 00:00:01,515 DEBUG [[(JSK) mux request dispatch][/][tid=1234][compileController.Code]] - compileController.Code finished in 9ms
2016-11-02 00:00:01,578 INFO  [[(JSK) mux request dispatch][/][tid=2345][compileController.Code]] - Received request for test request: [ticket=test101]
2016-11-02 00:00:01,582 INFO  [[(JSK) mux request dispatch][/][tid=2345][compileController.Code]] - request: [ticket=test101] found in cache, returning from Cache
2016-11-02 00:00:01,582 DEBUG [[(JSK) mux request dispatch][/][tid=2345][compileController.Code]] - compileController.Code finished in 4ms
2016-11-02 00:00:08,606 INFO  [[(JSK) mux request dispatch][/][tid=6789][compileController.Code]] - Received request for test request: [ticket=test102]
2016-11-02 00:00:08,606 INFO  [[(JSK) mux request dispatch][/][tid=6789][compileController.Code]] - request: [ticket=test102] found in cache, returning from Cache
2016-11-02 00:00:08,606 DEBUG [[(JSK) mux request dispatch][/][tid=6789][compileController.Code]] - compileController.Code finished in 0ms
2016-11-02 00:00:09,320 INFO  [[(JSK) mux request dispatch][/][tid=566][compileController.Code]] - Received request for test request: [ticket=test102]
2016-11-02 00:00:09,320 INFO  [[(JSK) mux request dispatch][/][tid=566][compileController.Code]] - request: [ticket=test102] found in cache, returning from Cache
```

Comment: You shouldn't do this: `final<-rbind(final, df)`.

Comment: @nrussell, how would I combine all of the data into 1 data frame after reading all of the files?

Comment: I would overallocate a data.frame upfront and fill it progressively. And, although it probably won't make a significant difference, you should move this `paste(toMatch,collapse="|")` outside of the loop.

Comment: @nrussell, how?

Comment: You can start by providing an example of one of the log files.

Comment: `readr::read_log` may be helpful.

Comment: @nrussell, I've put a sample file

Comment: you do realize you included absolutely no lines from the log with `toMatch` strings, right? and, why would you `paste()` every time in the loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The major bottleneck in your code seems to be the call to `read.table`. By first concatenating the vector `xxx` into a single, newline-delimited string, you can pass it into data.tables's `fread`, which is much faster. Additionally, I've replaced the call to `grep` with `stri_subset` from the `stringi` package, and used data.table's `rbindlist` to combine everything, rather than iteratively calling `rbind`. I'm not sure how many files you have in total, but in the code below I'm using nine 180 MB files created from your sample.

```
library(data.table)
library(stringi)

files <- list.files(
    "/tmp",
    pattern = "logfile",
    full.names = TRUE
)
re <- paste(
    c("compile.cancelSwapCode", "compile.insertCode", 
      "compile.getCode", "compile.getCodes",
      "compile.getCodeWithAnalysis", "DEBUG"),
    collapse = "|"
)

system.time({

final <- rbindlist(
  lapply(files, function(f) {
      lines <- readLines(f)
      fread(
          paste0(
              stri_subset(lines, regex = re), 
              collapse = "\n"
          ),
          header = FALSE,
          sep = " ",
          colClasses = "character"
      )
  })
)    

})
#    user  system elapsed 
# 136.664   0.628 137.378
```

---

It looks like you are on Windows, so if you have [Rtools](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/) installed and are able to leverage Rcpp, you can shave off some more time by replacing `readLines` with a dead simple C++ equivalent:

```cpp
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <fstream>

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::CharacterVector read_lines(const char* file) {
    std::vector<std::string> res;
    res.reserve(10000);

    std::ifstream stream(file);
    std::string tmp;

    while (std::getline(stream, tmp)) {
        res.push_back(tmp);
    }

    return Rcpp::wrap(res);
}
```

---

Replacing `readLines` with `read_lines` in the above, I get

```
#   user  system elapsed 
# 39.200   0.376  39.596
```

---

If you aren't able to get up and running with Rtools and Rcpp, using `read_lines` from the `readr` package will still be faster than `readLines`. Here is a comparison of all three, reading in those nine 180 MB files:

```
system.time({ lapply(files, readLines) })
#    user  system elapsed 
# 287.136   1.140 288.471 

system.time({ lapply(files, readr::read_lines) })
#   user  system elapsed 
# 91.568   0.604  91.895

system.time({ lapply(files, read_lines) })
#   user  system elapsed 
# 24.204   0.652  24.862
```

---

**Update**

Regarding you comment below, IIUC you can do something like this:

```
final <- rbindlist(
    lapply(files, function(f) {
        lines <- readLines(f)
        matches <- stri_subset(lines, regex = re)
        data.table(
            stri_match_first(
                matches, 
                regex = "\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2} \\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}"
            )
        )
  })
)[,.(Count = .N), by = "V1"]
```

Comment: thank you for the answer, but it is not quite working yet. I get this error: Error in fread(paste0(stri_subset(lines, regex = re), collapse = "\n"),  : 
  Expected sep (' ') but new line, EOF (or other non printing character) ends field 11 when detecting types (

Comment: each line may be different in length. I was using read.table(fill=T) to address unequal lines. Any ideas how I could do this with your code pasted here?

Comment: I was under the impression that each match would result in the same number of columns. If this is not the case, then I would strongly advise against trying to store the final result in a `data.frame`. It would be much more sensible to use a `list` instead.

Comment: I am only interested in checking for the regular expression in the file, and count the number of incidents given the re per time provided at the beginning of the line (2016-11-02 00:00:01).